# Explicit description of pullback of Cartier divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'am reading Gortz's Alebraic Geometry and some question arises.

Let $ f : X \to Y $ be a morphism of schemes. Assume that the homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X$ given by $f$ extends to a homomorphism $\mathcal{K}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{K}_X$.
Then in p.312 he argues that we obtain a homomorphism $\mathcal{K}_Y^{\times}/ \mathcal{O}_{Y}^{\times}\to f_{*}\mathcal{K}_X^{\times}/ f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\times}\to f_{*}(\mathcal{K}_X^{\times}/ \mathcal{O}_{X}^{\times})$, and hence we has a homomorphism between cartier divisors :

$$ f^{*} : \operatorname{Div}(Y) = \Gamma{(Y, \mathcal{K}_Y^{\times}}/\mathcal{O}_{Y}^{\times}) \to \Gamma{(X,\mathcal{K}_X^{\times}}/\mathcal{O}_X^{\times})=\operatorname{Div}(X)$$

, called the pullback.

And let $D$ be a cartier divisor on $Y$. Then we can describe $D$ more concretely (his book p.301) ; i.e. $D$ is given by a tuple $(U_i,f_i)_{i}$, where $Y = \cup_iU_i$ is an open covering and where $f_i \in \Gamma(U_i, \mathcal{K}_Y)$ is the quotient of two regular elements of $\Gamma(U_i,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ such that
$f_i f_j^{-1} := f_i |_{U_i \cap U_j} f_j^{-1}|_{U_i \cap U_j} \in \Gamma(U_i \cap U_j, \mathcal{O}_Y^{\times})$.

**Now, my question is**, can we describe $f^{*}(D)$ more concretely ; i.e., in terms of $(U_i, f_i)_i $ and the $f$?

This question originates from following proof of the his book, Proposition 15.26 : [image]

**Why the underlined statement is true?**

I'm trying to understand the underlined statement by approaching via explicit description of $j_x^{*}(D)$. Anyway it seems that my question has value in itself.

It seems that it is possible to show our goal by the definitions of homomorphisms $\mathcal{K}_Y^{\times}/ \mathcal{O}_{Y}^{\times}\to f_{*}\mathcal{K}_X^{\times}/ f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\times}\to f_{*}(\mathcal{K}_X^{\times}/ \mathcal{O}_{X}^{\times})$ above but currently it seems a little bit complicated to me.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It’s just $(f^{-1}(U_i), f^{\sharp}f_i)$, no? ($f^{\sharp}$ being the structure morphism)

Comment: By $f^{\sharp}$, you mean the extended homomorphism $\mathcal{K}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{K}_X$? It seems that it needs some investigation : i.e., $(f^{-1}(U_i),f^{\sharp}_{U_i}(f_i))$ really satisfies the concrete defition of the Cartier divisors. ( Doest it requires some task?)

Comment: Yes, or more precisely the map $K_Y(U_i) \rightarrow K_X(f^{-1}(U_i))$ constructed from $f$. I think that the verification of the definition of Cartier divisors is more or less straightforward.

Comment: O.K. Thanks ~~  :)

Comment: Perhaps..can you give me an explicit description of the extended homomorhism $\bar{j^{\flat}_x} : \mathcal{K}_{X} \to j_{x,*}\mathcal{K}_{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})}$ from the canonical morphism $j_x : \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to X$ to understand the underlined statement?( Furthurmore to understand the the well-definedness of the (15.8.1) in the above image). I'm now trying to construct the extended homomorphism concretely.